# Pass object to viewcontroller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

In `Objective-C` if you need to pass an object to a `ViewController` you can do:

**in destination .h file**

```
@property NSObject * contact;
```

**in sending .m file**

```
MyVC *destVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myVC"];
destVC.contact = contact;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:destVC animated:YES];
```

I am trying to do this in Swift with this code:

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let destVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "contactDetail")
//Following line causes error
//destVC.contact = latestContact
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(destVC, animated: true)
```

The VC launches ok but when I try to pass it a variable with `destVC.contact = latestContact` then compiler says

> value of type `ViewController` has no such member contact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast it to your subclassed view controller. Say your contact details view controller class name is `ContactDetailsViewController`

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
if let destVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "contactDetail") as? ContactDetailsViewController {
   destVC.contact = latestContact
   self.navigationController!.pushViewController(destVC, animated: true)
}
```